# По какой книге лучше изучить C++?

Tags: книги, c++

Есть и Страуструп и Дейтел. Какая книга по-вашему самая простая и эффектная для самостоятельного изучения языка? Базовые знание уже есть.

Comment: Обратите внимание на [вопросы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&c%2B%2B/).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 0):

если Вы имеете начальное представление о `C++`, то Страуструп, пожалуй, сложно будет переварить. хотя его последнюю книгу 2011 года все хвалят, мол она более простая в понимании.

Дейтел - хороший вариант.

PS ещё много положительных отзывов слышал о книгах Липпмана "Язык программирования C++. Вводный курс" и Шилдта "С++: базовый курс".

Comment: спасибо. Тогда щас постараюсь найти его новую книгу и пригляну внутрь. Надеюсь пойму )

Comment: хорошо, удачного освоения материала!)

Comment: В.В.Подбельский, "Язык С++", М., "Финансы и статистика", 1995.